# Quick info and parameter info not available in intellisense when working with Jupyter extension in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter, intellisense

Intellisense works [perfectly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zwBDf.png) on a normal python script and you can easily see or hide the quick info by using the shortcut 'ctrl + space', but it [fails](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H2kob.png) to show any kind of info even after pressing 'ctrl+ space' when working with .ipynb file in VS Code using the extension 'jupyter'.

Is this a bug? Or do I need to enable some kind of option?

Answer (score 0):

Please ensure that you have the latest versions of VS Code, the Python extension, and the Jupyter extension. Then try installing the [Pylance extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.vscode-pylance), reloading when prompted, and trying again. If that doesn't get IntelliSense working, please report a bug at https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues so we can identify a fix.